# How can i set ForEach with multiple variables on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am looking to call two variables but the method I am trying to implement does not work.

Unfortunately, Xcode says Extra argument in call.

I am a newbie, can someone help me to understand what is going wrong ?

Thank you !!

```
struct Card {
    let content : [String]
    let names:[String]
    static let allCards:[Card] =     
        [
        Card(content: ["content1","content2"], names: ["name1","name2"]),
        Card(content: ["content3","content4"], names: ["name3","name4"])
        ]
   }
struct Play {
    
    let cards = Card.allCards.shuffled()
    var currentCardIndex = 0
    var currentCard:Card {
        cards[currentCardIndex]
    }
}
class GameViewModel {
    
    @Published var play = Play()
    var  cardContent:[String] {
        play.currentCard.content
    }
    var cardnames:[String] {
        play.currentCard.names
    }
}
struct CardView:View {
    let contentString:String
    let nameString:String
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
        Text(contentString)
        Text(nameString)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var viewModel = GameViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
/ Warning:  Extra argument in call 

            ForEach(viewModel.cardContent, viewModel.cardnames,id:\.self, content:{ card in
                CardView(contentString: card, nameString: card).frame(minWidth: 135, idealWidth: 250, maxWidth: 135, minHeight: 135, idealHeight: 250, maxHeight: 135, alignment: .center).aspectRatio(2/2, contentMode:.fit)
            })
            
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up `zip` it might help but just using `allCards` might be best

Comment: You should probably refactor your model.  Having linked or associated arrays is a code smell.  It is possible for them to get "out of sync".  You should create another struct that has `name` and `content` properties and then your `Card` can hold an array of these structs rather than two arrays of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause:
In `ForEach(viewModel.cardContent, viewModel.cardnames` either `viewModel.cardContent` or `viewModel.cardnames` is an *extra argument*, as `ForEach` can iterate only one array, and you are passing 2 arrays.

The simplest fix: pass only one array (`viewModel.play.cards`) in

```
ForEach(viewModel.play.cards, id:\.self, content: { card in
     CardView(contentString: card.content, nameString: card.names).frame(minWidth: 135, idealWidth: 250, maxWidth: 135, minHeight: 135, idealHeight: 250, maxHeight: 135, alignment: .center).aspectRatio(2/2, contentMode:.fit)
})
```

The example above still may not compile because of `CardView(contentString: card` constructor, but that's another problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it throws an error because you are passing more than the available arguments to constructor of `ForEach`

You can see the below available constructor of `ForEach`, then you come to know which argument you are passing it as extra to the constructor

```
init(_ data: Data, @AccessibilityRotorContentBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)

init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, @AccessibilityRotorContentBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)

init(_ data: Data, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)

init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)

init<C>(_ data: Binding<C>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Binding<C.Element>) -> Content) where Data == LazyMapSequence<C.Indices, (C.Index, ID)>, ID == C.Element.ID, C : MutableCollection, C : RandomAccessCollection, C.Element : Identifiable, C.Index : Hashable

init<C>(_ data: Binding<C>, id: KeyPath<C.Element, ID>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Binding<C.Element>) -> Content) where Data == LazyMapSequence<C.Indices, (C.Index, ID)>, C : MutableCollection, C : RandomAccessCollection, C.Index : Hashable
```

And in your code

```
//viewModel.cardnames is the extra argument you are passing to ForEach
            ForEach(viewModel.cardContent, viewModel.cardnames,id:\.self, content:{ card in
                CardView(contentString: card, nameString: card).frame(minWidth: 135, idealWidth: 250, maxWidth: 135, minHeight: 135, idealHeight: 250, maxHeight: 135, alignment: .center).aspectRatio(2/2, contentMode:.fit)
            })
```